# Концепция модулей в JavaScript (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, модули

Объясните, пожалуйста, какое назначение у экспортирования и импортирования отдельных модулей, если в процессе подключения JS-файлов с данными модулями, они всё равно становятся доступными извне. Приведу пример.
Предположим, есть модуль

```
function sayHello(){
 console.log("Hello!");
}
export {sayHello}
```

и мы его импортируем в файле `index.js` . Чем конструкция html-страницы

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<!-- Тут с импортируемым модулем -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

будет отличаться от разметки типа

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="sayHello.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Ну, кроме лишнего запроса на сервер) Есть отличия в этой модульной системе ?

Comment: На данный момент система модудей жс это сплошной бардак и по факту модули нужны только для удобства разработки. Всё равно всё через бандлеры типа вебпака собирается в один файл, минифицируется и в таком виде подключается. Я думаю, что ещё не один год пройдёт, пока не примут единый стандарт модулей, который смогут поддерживать все браузеры. Но и это нас не спасёт, потому что, оказывается, ие11 ещё в ходу :(

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете делать import внутри своего скрипта при таком методе подключения на страницу. Я вобще не уверен, что это будет работать.
Такие модули корректно подключать через.

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: мне пожалуй не понятна сама концепция.... Какой смысл в разделении кода на модули если всё равно идет подключения в файле index.html .... возможно я чего-то не знаю, и данные модули можно подключать по каким-то условиям исполнения.

Comment: Вы подключаете один скрипт в страницу, а остальные вспомогательные в коде скрипта, и так до бесконечности. Ко всему прочему не засоряется общее пространство имен. То что "заиморчено" во вспомогательно скрипте и не экспортнуто видно не будет.